# Complex / join two video using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I use this command for join two video it working but output give audio i need video output.

```
ffmpeg -i 1047899717ssstiktok_1629776799.mp4 -i small.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

Comment: Copy and paste all of the text from the log.

Comment: here is no log it work i need video output  whats command i change?

Comment: I need to see info about each input, and info about your ffmpeg, to be able to provide an answer. That is why I asked for the "log". Copy and paste all of the text that shows up in the terminal/console/cmd when you run the ffmpeg command.